# Libreria printCE

Tags: c#, .net, imprimir

Alguien puede ayudarme a configurar la siguientes líneas de código para usar la librería `printCE.dll` en c# para conectar con una impresora `apex4`.

```
PrintInfo info = new PrintInfo();
info.color_mode = 0; //En blanco y Negro
info.printer = 22; //Impresora Datamax Apex
info.draft_mode = false;
info.end_page = -1;
info.paper = 3;
info.paper_height = 100;
info.paper_width = 300;
info.port = 3; //COM3
info.portrait = true;               
info.start_page = -1;
```

Comment: Hola Francisco. ¿Cual es el problema? Creo que deberías ser más concreto con cual es la dificultad que estas teniendo para que alguien pueda echarte una mano.

Comment: Estoy intentando imprimir una serie de datos conectando mi aplicacion desarrollada para windows mobile a una impresora datamax apex 4 por medio del uso de la libreria printce.dll y no consigo imprimir nada debido a la configuracion que muestro anteriormente